# MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring" : secret "rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring" not found

Tags: kubernetes, devops, ceph, rook-storage

I am trying to configure ceph on kubernetes cluster using rook, I have run the following commands:

```
kubectl apply -f common.yaml
```

```
kubectl apply -f operator.yaml
```

```
kubectl apply -f cluster.yaml
```

I have three worker nodes with atached volumes and on master, all the created pods are running except the rook-ceph-crashcollector pods for the three nodes, when I describe these pods I get this message

```
MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring" : secret "rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring" not found
```

However all the nodes are running and working

Comment: Could you please tell us where is your cluster located and which k8s version are you using?

Comment: I am running kubernetes on premis on hetzner vps machines

Comment: the version is v1.18.5

Comment: Have you tried to create the rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring manually? Execute: `kubectl -n rook-ceph create secret generic rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring`

Answer (score 2):

It is hard to exactly tell what might be the cause of this but there are few possibilities:

- Cluster networking problem between nodes
- Some possible leftover sockets in the `/var/lib/kubelet` directory related to rook ceph.
- A bug when connecting to an external Ceph cluster.

In order to fix your issue you can:

- Use Flannel and make sure it is using the right interface. Check the `kube-flannel.yml` file and see if it uses the `--iface=` option. Or alternatively try to use Calico.
- Clear the `./var/lib/rook/`, `./var/lib/kubelet/plugins/` and `./var/lib/kubelet/plugins_registry/` directories and reinstall the rook service.
- Create the `rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring` secret manually by executing: `kubectl -n rook-ceph create secret generic rook-ceph-crash-collector-keyring`.